# Can you violate the strict aliasing rule with std::aligned_union

Tags: c++, c++11, undefined-behavior, unions, strict-aliasing

Do the rules for unions, for example `[class.mem]`p20 also allow to a `std::aligned_union_t`?  For example if I store two pairs (`pair<const A, B>` and `pair<A, B>`) in an `std::aligned_union_t` with the non const pair active at all times.  Is accessing the `pair<const A>` type a violation of the strict aliasing rule?

The standard seems to hint in `[class.mem]`p20 that it is safe to access the const member of the pair even when the non const pair is active

```
union U {
    std::pair<A, B> pair;
    std::pair<const A, const B> const_pair;
};

U u = {A{}, B{}};
cout << u.const_pair.first << endl;
cout << u.const_pair.second << endl;
```

But is the same safe for `std::aligned_union` with placement `new` and `reinterpret_cast` to construct and get the right value?

(Assuming that `A` and `B` are standard layout)

Comment: "union" means "union".

Comment: @T.C. what do you mean?  Do you mean that both follow effectively the same rules?  Can you point me to where this is mentioned in the standard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the core language says "union", it means "union", i.e., "a class defined with the *class-key* `union`".  Not the pathetic library imitation known as `aligned_union_t`.

Comment: Why is the `aligned_union_t` a thing if it does not follow the same rules?  (i.e. uses a union to define the POD type it uses for storage under the hood)

Comment: @Curious Even if `aligned_union_t` is actually a union, CIS only applies to actual members of the union, not to the thing you placement-newed over it.

Comment: Hmm.. What does does CIS stand for?

Comment: ...common initial sequence

Comment: Also on a related note - the standard documentation for `reinterpret_cast` does not seem to say that it is safe to access an object of type `T` through a `reinterpret_cast` on it's storage (either through a raw array, etc.)  Then how does one validate uses of `reinterpret_cast`s with `aligned_union`s?

Comment: What I mean is, is it undefined behavior to allocate storage for one of n types in an `std::aligned_union` and then implement tagged access over that?  Or does one have to use a union?

Comment: @Curious A by-the-spec `aligned_union`-based implementation of tagged union needs to either store the pointer returned by the placement new or use `launder`.

Comment: You can't `reinterpret_cast` it every time?

Comment: You can, but you have to launder the result.

Comment: Got it yea. My understanding about that was wrong previously. I assumed that was implementable without help from the compiler. Makes sense

Comment: Do you know why `aligned_union` takes a `Len` argument?